# Proving complex integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Hi I'm a bit lost with the following question and was wondering if anyone could help:

Prove that $\ \int_c (z-a)^n dz = 2\pi i $ iF c is given by $\ z(t) = a+ e^{it}, 0 \le t \le 2 \pi $ and $\ n = -1 $

Show that the integral is zero for all other values of n ∈ Z.

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $n \geq 2$, you can use the Cauchy theorem,also for $n =0$. For $n$ negative you can use the Laurent series.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг: I suspect that this exercise is part of a course and it logically precedes Cauchy's theorem (the factor of $\frac1{2\pi i}$ in Cauchy's formula comes from this computation). So it is better to compute the integral directly, in my opinion.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the comment. It's too late, there's an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just compute the integral:
$$
\int_c (z-a)^n \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} \! e^{nit} i e^{it} \, dt
= \int_0^{2\pi} \! i \, e^{(n+1)it} \, dt
$$
When $n=-1$, the integrand reduces to $i$ and the integral is $2\pi i$.

When $n\ne -1$, the integral is zero by the fundamental theorem of calculus, because $e^{(n+1)it}$ is periodic with period $2\pi$.